# Is AIR Native Extension compatible with Kinect v2?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, kinect

I would like to purchase a Kinect v2 and I was wondering if it was possible to program it using actionscript.

Thanks!

Comment: probably not at this point and unlikely in the future.

Comment: Well, there is a Native Extension for the first Kinect. Will it work with v2? No. You will probably have to make your own Extension with the Kinect SDK.